# Strange content in JSON deserialization result

Tags: servicestack, json-deserialization, servicestack-text

Given this request DTO

```cs
public class CreateRecordRequest {
    public Dictionary<string, object> Record { get; set; }
}
```

when I call the service passing this JSON

```js
{
    "Record": {
        "File": {
            "name": "DSC_3493_4_5.jpg",
            "extension": ".jpg",
            "size": 596002,
            "rawFile": {}
        },
        "Notes": "",
        "Type": ""
    }
}
```

`File` has the deserialized value `"{"`. Since ServiceStack has no way of knowing which object `File` maps to, I'm curious why it doesn't deserialize it as a dictionary (`"{"` is inexplicable). What is the easiest way to customize deserialization of a single value like this? I'm working with Kendo's upload control and this is the JSON it submits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's an `object` the Serializer doesn't know what type to dehydrate this into, you can force it to use a `Dictionary<string,string>` with:

```
JsConfig.ConvertObjectTypesIntoStringDictionary = true;
```

Comment: If I define a File class, is there an easy way to deserialize it to that, other than copying the dictionary values?

Comment: Only for reference types where you have an `object` defined. If the Schema specified a `File` type instead, it should use that.